# if form.is_valid() return errors when using get_or_create

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

```
class Books(models.Model):
    book_file = models.FileField(
        upload_to="books",
        validators=[validate_book_extension],
        verbose_name="book",
    )
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, default=None)
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default="")
    coauthors = models.ManyToManyField(CoAuthor, blank=True)
    publisher = models.ForeignKey(
        Publisher,
        on_delete=models.SET_DEFAULT,
        default=None,
        related_name="books_published",
    )
    genres = models.ManyToManyField(Genre)
    edition = models.IntegerField(default=None)

    description = models.TextField(blank=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

i am having trouble with form validation when uploading a book to a database. The model has fields for authors and coauthors with ForeignKey and ManyToManyField relationships, and you're using the `get_or_create` method in the view function that handles the submission of fields with ForeignKey and ManyToManyField relationship. However, the `if form.is_valid()` statement returns errors and if i don't check if the form is valid the form submits. Below is the error that pops up.

[image: The Error]

**views.py**

```
@login_required
def addbook(request):
    if not request.user.is_superuser:
        return redirect(notfound)
    else:
        books = Books.objects.all()
        genres = Genre.objects.all()
        authors = Author.objects.all()
        coauthors = CoAuthor.objects.all()
        publishers = Publisher.objects.all()
        form = BookForm()
        if request.method == "POST":
            form = BookForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
            if form.is_valid():
                book = request.FILES.get("book_file")
                title = request.POST.get("title")
                genres_name = request.POST.getlist("genres")
                author_name = request.POST.get("author")
                co_authors = request.POST.getlist("coauthors")
                publisher_name = request.POST.get("publisher")
                author, created = Author.objects.get_or_create(
                    name=author_name.title())
                publisher, created = Publisher.objects.get_or_create(
                    name=publisher_name.title()
                )
                
                book = Books.objects.create(
                    title=title.title(),
                    publisher=publisher,
                    edition=request.POST.get("edition"),
                    author=author,
                    book_file=book,
                )
                for genre in genres_name:
                    genre, created = Genre.objects.get_or_create(
                        name=genre.lower())
                    book.genres.add(genre)
                if co_authors:
                    for co_author in co_authors:
                        coauthor, created = CoAuthor.objects.get_or_create(
                            name=co_author.title()
                        )
                        book.coauthors.add(coauthor)
        else:
            form = BookForm()
        context = {
            "form": form,
            "genres": genres,
            "authors": authors,
            "publishers": publishers,
            "books": books,
            "coauthors": coauthors
        }
        return render(request, "books/addbook.html", context)
```

**Forms.py**

```
class BookForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Books
        fields = "__all__"
        labels = {"coauthors": "Co Author"}
        widgets = {
            "genres": forms.TextInput(
                attrs={
                    "list": "genres",
                    "class": "form-control genres-input ",
                    "placeholder": "Enter Genre",
                }
            ),
            "book_file": forms.ClearableFileInput(
                attrs={
                    "id": "formFile",
                    "class": "form-control form-control-sm",
                    "placeholder": "Select Book",
                }
            ),
            "author": forms.TextInput(
                attrs={
                    "list": "author",
                    "class": "form-control ",
                    "placeholder": "Enter Author Name",
                }
            ),
            "coauthors": forms.TextInput(
                attrs={
                    "list": "co-author",
                    "id": "co_authors",
                    "class": "form-control coauthor-name",
                    "placeholder": "Enter Co-authors Name",
                }
            ),
            "publisher": forms.TextInput(
                attrs={
                    "list": "publisher",
                    "class": "form-control ",
                    "placeholder": "Enter Publisher",
                }
            ),
            "title": forms.TextInput(
                attrs={"class": "form-control ", "placeholder": "Enter Title"}
            ),
            "edition": forms.NumberInput(
                attrs={"class": "form-control ", "placeholder": "Enter Edition"}
            ),
        }
```

**Template**

```
{% extends 'main.html' %} 
{% block mymessage %}
    <title>Upload Books</title>
    <style>
      body {
        background-image: url("/static/signup/img/05.jpg");
        background-attachment: fixed;
        background-size: cover;
        background-position: center;
        background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
        background-blend-mode: darken;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container mt-5">
      <form action="/addbook/" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="addbook" class="needs-validation">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
        <div class="mb-3 form-floating ">
          {{ form.title }}
          <label for="{{ form.title.id_for_label }}" class="form-label">{{ form.title.label }}</label>
          
        </div>
    
        <div class="mb-3 form-floating col">
          {{ form.author }}
          <label for="{{ form.author.id_for_label }}" class="form-label">{{ form.author.label }}</label>
          <datalist id="author">
            {% for author in authors %}
            <option value="{{ author.name }}">{{ author.name }}</option>
            {% endfor %}
          </datalist>
        </div>
        
        <div class="mb-1 coauthor-parent">
          <div class="coauthor form-floating">
            {{ form.coauthors }}
            <label for="{{ form.coauthors.id_for_label }}" class="form-label">{{ form.coauthors.label }}
              <span>(Optional)</span>
            </label>
            <datalist id="co-author">
              {% for coauthor in coauthors %}
              <option value="{{ coauthor.name }}">{{ coauthor.name }}</option>
              {% endfor %}
            </datalist>
          </div>
          <div class="buttons">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary mt-2 add-coauthor">
              +
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>

        
        <div class="mb-3 form-floating">
          {{ form.publisher }}
          <label for="{{ form.publisher.id_for_label }}" class="form-label">{{ form.publisher.label }}</label>
          <datalist id="publisher">
            {% for publisher in publishers %}
            <option value="{{ publisher.name }}">{{ publisher.name }}</option>
            {% endfor %}
          </datalist>
        </div>
    
        <div class="mb-1 genre-parent">
          <div class="genre form-floating">
            {{ form.genres }}
            <label for="{{ form.genres.id_for_label }}" class="form-label">{{ form.genres.label }}</label>
            <datalist id="genres">
              {% for genre in genres %}
              <option value="{{ genre.name }}">{{ genre.name }}</option>
              {% endfor %}
            </datalist>
          </div>
          <div class="buttons">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary mt-2 add-genre">
              +
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
    
        <div class="mb-3 form-floating">
          {{ form.edition }}
          <label for="{{ form.edition.id_for_label }}" class="form-label">{{ form.edition.label }}</label>
        </div>
    
        <div class="input-group mb-3 input-group-sm">
          {{ form.book_file }}
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mb-3">Create</button>
    
        <div class="mb-3 text-danger">{{ form.errors }}</div>
        {% endif %}
        <script src="/static/js/genre.js" async></script>
        <script src="/static/js/coauthor.js" async></script>
      </form>
    </div>
  </body>
{% endblock %}
```

What i want to achieve is to be able to use my **forms.py**, **template** and validate in my **view function** without getting the errors i am getting

Comment: According to that image, one of the errors is that the "author" field is empty.  If it is actually empty, then it seems like displaying an error is the correct response.  Or are you saying that the error is wrong and the "author" field actually wasn't empty?  Or that it's okay for that field to be empty and it shouldn't count as an error?

Comment: My code works fine. in the view function, if you remove the `if form.is_valid()` the form submits to database but when it is added, it raises those error and the reason why is that i use a `TextInput` Widget for a `ForeignKey` and  a `ManyToMany` field in my **forms.py**. So what i want to achieve is to be able to bypass these errors and submit my form and also be able to perform validation of my own